# How To Check Entry of New Rows In ADW?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I Have scheduled various pipeline that copys incremental data from On Premises SQL DB to Azure Datawarehouse, sometimes there are some issues with the number of rows, like the row count not matching or same rows getting copied, How can I check what rows are getting copied over to the Datawarehouse so that If there is a redundancy or discrepancy I should be aware about.

I know that ADF V1 Pipeline Monitoring feature just shows the number of rows that got copied over, but not what rows got copied over, is there a way so that I can find out what got copied and what not.

This things become much more hard when we are dealing with the tables which are having million rows.

Answer (score 0):

Since Azure SQL Datawarehouse doesnt have support for primary key constraints, you can create staging tables where you insert the new data, and then call a stored procedure where you compare this new data with what you already have, and only insert the new rows into the actual tables.

This isnt a very good practice, the best way is to control the insertion of new rows in an actual ETL process, if you dont have this you might be better off with an Azure SQL server that supports almost everything that the on premise sql server supports, and not a warehouse.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The pattern for DW is usually to land your data into a stage table and then continue processing your data into your prod tables with T-SQL. Using this pattern, you can simply run a SELECT COUNT_BIG(*) FROM  to get the row count in the staging table before you continue processing.